# Show different messages on Ajax based form submission

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on a a script to process the form submission based on AJAX. I am able to submit the form using AJAX and show a success message.
However I want to show different messages based on background form data processing. For example, when the user registration form is submitted it is being entered into 2 systems, so I want to show - User created in system One then user created in system 2, then an email is being sent, so I want to show email is being sent. and so on.

I am currently using the jquery ajax method. here is my sample code.

```
formData = jQuery('form#Registration').serialize();
 jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'form_process.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (msg, textStatus, xhr) {
                jQuery('#success_msg').html( msg );
            }
        });
```

So how I can show different messages base on data processing.

Thanks

Comment: You are just showing the output of your php script so you need to adapt that as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

So, for this you need to do your processings at the serverside and then you can echo out the message you want to show:

```
if(condition){
    echo "User created in system One.";
} else if(condition){
    echo "User created in system Two.";
}else{
    echo "Email sent.";
}
```

now at the `jQuery.ajax()` you need to change the `dataType` to:

```
dataType:"text"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we have login.js. we will get the data from login form. i think you will understand from the given code.

```
  var adminlogin={
    init:function(){
        this.formSubmitEvent();
    },
    formSubmitEvent:function(){
        _this=this;
        $("#adminlogin-form").submit(function(){
            if((result=formValidation("adminlogin-form"))&&(result['error']))
            {
                return false;
            }

            data=getFormObj("adminlogin-form");

            _this.login(data);
            return false;
        });
    },
    login:function(data){
        $.ajax({
            url:"admin/login.php",
            data:data,
            success:function(data){
                if(data.adminid)
                {
                    window.location = "home.php";

                }else
                {
                    showError(data.reason);
                }
            },
            error:function(data){
                if(data.responseText=="")
                {
                    showError("Some error occured in server");
                }
                else
                {
                    showError(data.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
    }
};

adminlogin.init();
```

try like this